# getProductById from firebase using query params

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript

I am trying to fetch products dynamically upon clicking on NativeScript app item. I am using firebase for the moment and I am not familiar with it.

Here is the method

```js
  getDish(id: number): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish>(baseURL +'dishes.json/'+ id)
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }
```

and Here is the firebase target "[firebaseName]firebaseio.com/dishes/0" [1/2/3/4 etc].

What am I doing wrong?

If you have particular correction or link that will be 
highly appreciated.

Comment: Result: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.json` suffix needs to be last in the URL:

```
return this.http.get<Dish>(baseURL +'dishes/'+ id + '.json')
```

Comment: Man! You saved a day in the life of a beginner twice. Thanks  Frank. You are so generous.